# PyOpenGL. glVertexPointer loads RAM to infinity

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

All works, but RAM loads very fast, i think  its glVertexPointer in cycle.
Here is my simplified code

```
...
pygame.init()
display = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
glClearColor(4/255, 4/255, 22/255, 1)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
...

while True:
    ....

    vertices = vertices @ A           # A = np.array((3, 3)), vertices = np.array((N, 3)), N~2000
    vertices1 = np.ravel(vertices)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices1)
    # glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices1.nbytes, vertices1)
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, l_v)
...
```

if comment this, RAM not loads:

```
# glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices1)
```

i'm new one in OpenGL, and don't know right ways to do what i want. I want to manipulate with vertices dynamically in time. And it so happened that my computer is old, and installed OpenGL 2.0. Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is solved my problem with RAM

```
import array
vertices1 = array.array('f', vertices1)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices1.tobytes() )
```

but converting lowered fps from 100 to 30, i use two converting for a cycle

upd.

this works ideal

```
vertices1 = np.ravel(vertices)
vertices1 = np.array(vertices1, dtype='f')
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices1.tobytes() )
```